# Apple reject my app because of not include functionality to allow users to view or select items from the Files app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios11, icloud

In my app I am get video from gallery using below method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
}
```

But Apple is rejected app and required to include functionality to select video items from Files app.

Here is Apple give me the reason:

> We noticed that your app enables users to view and select files, but
>   it does not include functionality to allow users to view or select
>   items from the Files app and the user's iCloud documents, as required
>   by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Comment: you added permission in .info file?

Comment: @ChiragKothiya yes Buddy Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description , i set above permission into .plist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that they want you to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to enable users to select video files from cloud services as well as from the photo library in accordance with clause 2.5.15

Apple wants their customers to have a good experience with their device and the apps they run on it, so it makes sense for your app to support all relevant iOS features.

You can create a show a document picker to select video files using:

```
let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.movie"], in: .import)
picker.delegate = self
self.show(picker, sender: self)
```

You will need to implement some delegate code to handle the picked document.  For example, to copy the selected file into your app's documents directory:

```
extension ViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        if let pickedUrl = urls.first {
            let filename = pickedUrl.lastPathComponent
            self.filename.text = filename
            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            var documentsDirectory = paths[0]
            // Apend filename (name+extension) to URL
            documentsDirectory.appendPathComponent(filename)
            do {
                // If file with same name exists remove it (replace file with new one)
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectory.path) {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: documentsDirectory.path)
                }
                // Move file from app_id-Inbox to tmp/filename
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: pickedUrl.path, toPath: documentsDirectory.path)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(filename, forKey:"filename")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(documentsDirectory, forKey:"fileurl")
                self.fileURL = documentsDirectory
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable Answer but actually i really don't know how to start with  UIDocumentPickerViewController , if possible then give me some step , so i can open Videos With UIDocumentPickerViewController.

Comment: Thank you so much , actually my app is implemented in objective c , but never mind i know how to convert code swift to Objc. and finally i made it.

Answer (score 2):

I could see the clause in the review guideline

> 2.5.15 Apps that enable users to view and select files should include items from the Files app and the user’s iCloud documents.

Looks like you should add `UIDocumentPickerViewController` support as @Paulw11 pointed out